# Group Sequential SQL Records

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, time

Looking for a way to group sequential timeclock records into a single row.

The source system has an identity column, employee id, date and in/out flag (1=in & 2=out). Note that the

```
ID          EmployeeID    DATE                   InOut
1019374     5890          2008-08-19 14:07:14    1
1019495     5890          2008-08-19 18:17:08    2
1019504     5890          2008-08-19 18:50:40    1
1019601     5890          2008-08-19 22:06:18    2
```

I am looking for sql that would give me the following result

```
EmployeeID ClockIn             BreakStart          BreakEnd            ClockOut
5890       2008-08-19 14:07:14 2008-08-19 18:17:08 2008-08-19 18:50:40 2008-08-19 22:06:18
```

Note that the ID in the source system is not always sequential because of timeclock edits. Date should be chronological. If only two punches exist, I will need to have the clock in and clock out dates populated with no breaks (or something consistent that I can extract with a case statement). No breaks example below:

```
EmployeeID ClockIn             BreakStart          BreakEnd            ClockOut
5890       2008-08-19 14:07:14                                         2008-08-19 22:06:18
```

Sql version is 2008 R2

Thanks in advance, I can't figure out how to get this to work consistently and your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if there are more clock ins and outs than 2 of each?

Comment: Good point, I would need some sort of error/manual review flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `ROW_NUMBER()` function and a windowed `COUNT()` to handle the no break days:

```
;with cte as (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeID, CAST(dt AS DATE) ORDER BY dt) RN
                      ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeID, CAST(dt AS DATE)) Dt_CT
              FROM Table1)
SELECT EmployeeID
      ,Dt = CAST(dt AS DATE)
      ,ClockIn = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN DT END)
      ,BreakStart =  MAX(CASE WHEN Dt_CT = 4 AND RN = 2 THEN DT END)
      ,BreakEnd =  MAX(CASE WHEN Dt_CT = 4 AND RN = 3 THEN DT END)
      ,ClockOut = MAX(CASE WHEN (Dt_CT = 2 AND RN = 2) OR RN = 4 THEN DT END)
FROM cte
GROUP BY EmployeeID
        ,CAST(dt AS DATE)
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7b9443/1/0)

This is set by day, so a clockout after midnight wouldn't work, and odd number of punches would also be problematic, but for a simple world like your example this will do.

Comment: Can you see a way of doing this using only a view?

Comment: You can put this query in a view: `CREATE VIEW Blah AS WITH ...`

Comment: For what it's worth, I think this is not a good way to do the job. You're optimizing for the non-error case, but everything will be blown to smithereens if punches are unusual. This is application-level business rules programming, and I think it's complicated enough that it shouldn't be done in the data layer.

Comment: @ErikE We don't know enough to make that determination, you'd be right if it's just a dumb punch clock which fills a table with problems, but I've worked with punch systems that produce very clean data, with things like  automatic punch out at 11:59:59 pm and punch in at 12:00 am when someone punches out after midnight.  Your point is valid though, this mightn't belong in the data layer.