# Grouping couple of records of 'in' and 'out', into 'sessions'. By SQL query or by programming

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, ms-access

I have a table (on Microsoft Access, but could be on SQL server or similar), with worker in/out registry.

Every 'In' of a worker is a record with his PersonalID, TimeOfEvent, and kind of event ("In" or "Out").

At the end of the way - I'll have to calculate the differences in time between each "In" and "Out".

But as a middle step - I want to make a 'group' query (in Microsoft Access query builder or writing SQL clause) that will add a unique "SessionID" to each couple of "In" and "Out" record. So I'll have many "Sessions", each of them with 2 records - same PersonID, one "In" event, and out "Out event" that is later than the "In" event linked to it.

Such a query would be great, but writing a VBA helper function, or more complicated SQL inner join could also be possible for me.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: (1) Sample data and desired results would really help your question.  (2) Avoiding MS Access would probably simplify whatever query you need.

Comment: I'll be glad to put here data and sample results. How can I copy a sample table from MS-Access? And as I said - MS-Access query builder could be easy and very helpful for others also, but I'm open to SQL / VBA / VB solutions as well. Many thanks!

Comment: ctrl-c and ctrl-v?

Comment: What if there are two IN in a row etc? Which should the next OUT relate to?

Comment: 'but could be on SQL server or similar' - similar is the key word, no 2 sql dialects are the same , even msaccess to sqlserver

Comment: btw - found now [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319075/group-sequential-sql-records) very similar question. My situation is the same, but looking for broader range of solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This question is tagged vb.net so I'm assuming that's an option, even though question says VBA.  Also we don't have anywhere near enough info for a complete solution, so here's so code that could be used to do the basics.  You'd need to fill in the rest where needed or come back here with a more specific question.

```
Public Class Session
    Public PersonId As Integer
    Public SessionStart As DateTime
    Public SessionEnd As Nullable(Of DateTime)

    Public Sub New(Id As Integer, Start As DateTime)
        PersonId = Id
        SessionStart = Start
    End Sub

End Class

//Assumes dt contains your list of events
Public Function GetSessions(dt As DataTable) As List(Of Session)

    Dim Sessions As New List(Of Session)
    Dim OpenSession As Session
    For Each rw As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim id As Integer = CInt(rw("PersonID"))
        OpenSession = (From s As Session In Sessions
                       Where s.PersonId = id AndAlso s.SessionEnd Is Nothing
                       Select s).FirstOrDefault()

        If CBool(rw("In")) Then
            If OpenSession IsNot Nothing Then
                //Two In records found with no Out between.  Handle that error here.
            Else
                Sessions.Add(New Session(id, rw("TimeOfEvent")))
            End If
        Else
            If OpenSession Is Nothing Then
                //Out record found with no matching In.  Handle that error here.
            Else
                OpenSession.SessionEnd = rw("TimeOfEvent")
            End If
        End If
    Next

    //This code finds any unclosed sessions.  Up to you whether that's an error or not.  If not, just remove them from the Sessions list
    Dim OpenSessions As List(Of Session) = (From s As Session In Sessions
                                            Where s.SessionEnd Is Nothing
                                            Select s).ToList()


    Return Sessions  'This is a list of sessions containing Id, Start & End time.  Do what you want with it

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this code. I'm seeing the approach, and will look into it and test it soon. Vb.Net is definitely an option for me, although I assume many are looking over the net for a SQL kind of 'magic clause' that will solve it. Many thanks again, hope to report back soon.